# Redmine install process rake db:migrate does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, installation, redmine

I am in process of installing Redmine app via [RedmineInstall documentation](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall) I try step 5 :

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

then error shows :

```
bundler: command not found: rake
Install missing gem executables with ´bundle install´
```

I use redmine 3.3.0 64 for windows

I use redmine gemfile and rake was installed (i see `Using rake 11.2.2`)

I tried reinstall it via bundle install or gem install/uninstall, but did not help (see Successfully installed rake-11.2.2 but rake do not work).

I tried this command from ruby/bin directory or redmine directory not success.

I do not understand, that rake is successfully installed, but when i try use it with bundle it says that command not found.
The problem may be in the directory where the Redmine or rake?

Comment: have you done 'bundle install'

Comment: are you using rbenv or rvm? You might be using a different ruby gem set for the directory you are installing it in.

Comment: have you tried just "rake db:migrate"

Comment: I followed the installation instructions and bundle install was succesfully done a show cca 30 installed gem include rake

Comment: Actually i tried "rake db:migrate" (in redminde directory where is rakefile) and it do something and say rmagick is not installed (i will install it and post info there)

Comment: if it will be work, than mahatmanich can create answer and i will marked it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `rake db:migrate` in your redmine directory without `bundle exec` and see if that resolves your issue.

*Bundler usually provides bin stubs for rake and other gem files, so that `bundle exec` is not necessary or will even fail because it will look in an other gem directory where, in this case, rake might not be installed.*